# How to create setup of windows forms application with my finger print driver in visual studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have created an ekyc application in windows form application (c#) in which finger is scanned with one device named as FM220 . What I want to do? I have to create a setup file with Device driver. So when I run setup file , it also install my driver.

I don't want to install driver separately to work.

Please help me.

Comment: Do you already have a setup project / installer for your application?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you read these tutorials.

- [How to create a custom driver installation script](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/drivers/develop/create-a-custom-driver-installation-script)
- [Building a Driver with Visual Studio and the WDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/drivers/develop/building-a-driver)

The idea is to put the drivers as part of your installation procedure, or even as part of your application startup. You'll have to consider things like permissions, etc. It's quite hard to answer your question with the detail provided at the moment. I think these resources should get you on the right track.